# Why Observable.fromIterable miss some data in some case?

Tags: rx-java2

I write a sample to test `flatMap` operator in RxJava2, below is the code snippet:

```
Observable<Integer> observable = ObservableCreate.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<Integer> emitter) throws Exception {
            emitter.onNext(1);
            emitter.onNext(2);
            emitter.onNext(3);
            emitter.onNext(4);
            emitter.onComplete();
        }
    });
    Disposable disposable = observable.flatMap(new Function<Integer, ObservableSource<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableSource<String> apply(Integer i) throws Exception {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(3);
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                list.add("I am from apply:" + i);
                //list.add("I am from apply:" + i + "_" + j);
            }
            log("apply: " + listToString(list));
            return Observable.fromIterable(list);
        }
    })
    .flatMap(new Function<String, ObservableSource<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableSource<String> apply(String s) throws Exception {
            return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<String>() {
                @Override
                public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<String> emitter) throws Exception {
                    emitter.onNext("flatMap--" + s);
                    emitter.onComplete();
                }
            });
        }
    })
    .subscribe(
        s -> log("accept: " + s)
        , throwable -> log(throwable.getMessage())
        , () -> log("complete!")
    );
```

Do you think what logs will print? Is it going to something like the following?

```
apply: [I am from apply:1, I am from apply:1, I am from apply:1]
accept: flatMap--I am from apply:1
accept: flatMap--I am from apply:1
accept: flatMap--I am from apply:1
apply: [I am from apply:2, I am from apply:2, I am from apply:2]
accept: flatMap--I am from apply:2
accept: flatMap--I am from apply:2
accept: flatMap--I am from apply:2
apply: [I am from apply:3, I am from apply:3, I am from apply:3]
accept: flatMap--I am from apply:3
accept: flatMap--I am from apply:3
accept: flatMap--I am from apply:3
apply: [I am from apply:4, I am from apply:4, I am from apply:4]
accept: flatMap--I am from apply:4
accept: flatMap--I am from apply:4
accept: flatMap--I am from apply:4
complete!
```

I also think that I'll get these logs, but I am wrong, I only get two for each string, just like this:

```
apply: [I am from apply:1, I am from apply:1, I am from apply:1]
accept: flatMap--I am from apply:1
accept: flatMap--I am from apply:1
apply: [I am from apply:2, I am from apply:2, I am from apply:2]
accept: flatMap--I am from apply:2
accept: flatMap--I am from apply:2
apply: [I am from apply:3, I am from apply:3, I am from apply:3]
accept: flatMap--I am from apply:3
accept: flatMap--I am from apply:3
apply: [I am from apply:4, I am from apply:4, I am from apply:4]
accept: flatMap--I am from apply:4
accept: flatMap--I am from apply:4
complete!
```

I try to find the reason of this, so I add some breakpoints and debug step in step,  unfortunately, I get the right result after debugging. I am so confused, does `fromIterable` operator miss some data in some case?

Comment: The code you provided should always produce the expected output: 1 `apply:` followed by 3 `accept:`. If this is not the code you are having trouble with, please check what you did or didn't include in this post.

Comment: @akarnokd That is all the test code, from the coding perspective I will always get the expected output, but when run it on the device, I get the wrong result, that's why I'm confused, you can try it as well.

Comment: Then you have to diagnose the issue. Have `j` go from 1 to 4-5-6-etc, add `j` to the mapping to see if there is a pattern to the lost data. Your logging mechanism may also simply not log events. You can also collect all results into a list via `toList` and then log that at the `subscribe`. If that also misses items, then come back with more details such as device type, Android version, library versions, etc.

Comment: I tried it out, works as you predicted with 3 accept.  Recompile your code.. :)

Comment: @akarnokd thanks, I didn't realized that the logcat could make this error, I new a list to save the string at the `subscribe` as you say and then I find the result is correct, so my previous doubts vanished.

Comment: @Peter, you are right, my logcat make this mistake.